# Removing attributes from elements

Tags: c#, wix, linq-to-xml, wix3.5

I will start off with the code...

```
private static void File()
{
    wixFile = XDocument.Load(filePath);

    var fileElements = from file in wixFile.Descendants(GetWixNamespace() + "File")
                        select file;
    foreach (var file in fileElements)
    {
        if(file.Attributes("Name").Any())
            file.Attribute("Name").Remove();
    }
    wixFile.Save(filePath);
}
```

I actually check for quite a few attributes in the list and remove or correct them, but just to keep it short I took everything out except for one example of what I was doing.  The problem that I am having is that this code is not removing the Name attribute from anything like I would expect it.  When I put a break point in and watch it the "file" is getting updated as expected, but the changes are not going over to the wixFile when I save (or during the editing either).  I am not entirely sure what I am missing here so any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Here is a snippet of the code that is being changed:

```
<?define ApplicationPath=\\dwdata\develope\DocuWare\DW5\Mast_dsk\?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<Directory Id="DATADIR" Name="data">
                            <Directory Id="mysql" Name="mysql">
                                <Component Id="procs_priv.MYI" Guid="{1148181A-4818-434F-B2D1-E4B417586168}">
                                    <File Id="procs_priv.MYI" Name="procs_priv.MYI" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.ApplicationPath)Common\MySql\Server\data\mysql\procs_priv.MYI" />
                                </Component>
                                <Component Id="procs_priv.MYD" Guid="{A6688F48-71AF-4242-B6D0-CA69452A01B4}">
                                    <File Id="procs_priv.MYD" Name="procs_priv.MYD" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.ApplicationPath)Common\MySql\Server\data\mysql\procs_priv.MYD" />
                                </Component>
                                <Component Id="procs_priv.frm" Guid="{3025C26C-8DFF-43D4-A62A-79E78D2D807D}">
                                    <File Id="procs_priv.frm" Name="procs_priv.frm" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.ApplicationPath)Common\MySql\Server\data\mysql\procs_priv.frm" />
                                </Component>
                                <Component Id="proc.MYI" Guid="{FD4AA2E1-E059-4549-AE61-222878185A0A}">
                                    <File Id="proc.MYI" Name="proc.MYI" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.ApplicationPath)Common\MySql\Server\data\mysql\proc.MYI" />
                                </Component>
                                <Component Id="proc.MYD" Guid="{12EE6EE8-AC44-4601-84C5-14B27CF9A3E6}">
                                    <File Id="proc.MYD" Name="proc.MYD" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.ApplicationPath)Common\MySql\Server\data\mysql\proc.MYD" />
                                </Component>
                                <Component Id="proc.frm" Guid="{8A6F2928-5484-4B55-B75F-8475C684A091}">
                                    <File Id="proc.frm" Name="proc.frm" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.ApplicationPath)Common\MySql\Server\data\mysql\proc.frm" />
                                </Component>
</Directory>
</Directory>
</Wix>
```

I am getting the exact same thing back as well.  What I am trying to do is remove the "Name" attribute, but it just isn't working for whatever reason. The GetWiXNamespace() method returns the same namespace that is listed in the wix element as an XNamespace.

Comment: Consider to post enough information to allow us to easily reproduce the problem. So show us a sample of the XML you read in, show us what GetWixNamespace() returns, then show a sample of the XML you want and the one you currently get.

Comment: The questions is answered, but I still added the info you requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to read between the lines here and guess you are converting from an old version of WiX ( say 2.0 ) that required a File@Name attribute to a version ( say 3.0-3.6 ) that can infer this attribute and doesn't require it.

Here's some code that I just whipped up that I know works assuming the source xml is WiX 3.x.  I'm not sure what is wrong with your code but perhaps the method that returns the namespace hasn't accounted for the url change.

```
    XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi";
    var doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\before.wxs");
    var elements = from element in doc.Descendants( ns + "File")
                   where element.Attribute("Name") != null
                   select element;

    foreach (var element in elements)
    {
        element.Attribute("Name").Remove();
    }
    doc.Save(@"C:\after.wxs");


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <?define SourceDir="."?>
  <Module Id="YourModuleHere" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0">
    <Package Id="31c7722e-c2a0-4328-92a2-eacd443c10a9" Manufacturer="YourCompanyHere" InstallerVersion="200" />
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="MergeRedirectFolder">
        <Component Id="owc7CEF9B0C53324FC23404D2AAAB5D12B8" Guid="6898e947-fa51-8efb-bda4-2e256dea8ed1">
          <File Id="owf7CEF9B0C53324FC23404D2AAAB5D12B8" Name="bfsvc.exe" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\Windows\bfsvc.exe" KeyPath="yes" />
        </Component>
        <Component Id="owc8C6EA26177072C0006EEF8265FEF72A4" Guid="91737806-0b20-24ad-9653-cca05b5778fb">
          <File Id="owf8C6EA26177072C0006EEF8265FEF72A4" Name="explorer.exe" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\Windows\explorer.exe" KeyPath="yes" />
        </Component>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Module>
</Wix>
```

Comment: Thanks!  Just out of curiosity is there a difference between checking element.Attribute("Name") != Null   and element.Attributes("Name").Any()?

Comment: To be honest, there are so many ways to write LINQ queries with varying degrees of awesomeness that I'm just at the "get it done" level.  That's a fancy way of saying I don't know what I don't know yet.

Comment: Nice. I appreciate the honesty. Either way, your solution has helped me out greatly. Thanks again!